# Hybrid mobile app : chapters in video player and media saving format

Tags: react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to develop a Yoga mobile app which allows the user to play yoga videos.
My questions are about the video player :

1- Is there a package or a framework that allows the user to have chapters in the form of images above the play bar (like the image below) :

[Chapters in form of images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF85H.jpg)

2- Technically speaking, would it be better to save the videos/medias in a no SQL database (in Base64 format maybe ?)